# How to remove a specific jQuery event handler that does NOT have a namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, namespaces, click

I have a div element which has a bunch of event handlers attached to it by jQuery. 2 of these are **click** events, and I am trying to remove a specific one. I know that you can do:

```
jQuery("SELECTOR").off("click.NAMESPACE");
```

to only remove a specific click event with the given namespace. Hence, I used:

```
jQuery._data(HTML_ELEMENT, 'events');
```

to find out the namespace of the click event I want to remove, but it turns out to be empty. Is there a way to still achieve what I want? Thanks in advance.

Some more details:

The element has:

1. mouseover event
2. mouseout event
3. focus event
4. blur evet
5. keydown event
6. click event with namespace **nspaceA**
7. click event with **no** namespace

Basically, number 7 does a scroll on the page and I want to get rid of it. The problem is that these events are added from an external file and they use some variables that I don't have access to. Hence, I cannot remove all click events and add them back again (if that makes sense).

Comment: Could you give concrete example of what you are looking for, providing relevant code. Which event do you want to unbind??? I mean your title is: `How to remove a specific jQuery event handler that does NOT have a namespace?` BUT question in body is: `to find out the namespace of the click event I want to remove` so it's quite confusing what you are looking for

Comment: I've tried that but gives an error. @A.Wolff

Comment: That's correct, my bad!

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way without iterating through _data events object (not publibly supported, meaning can change from jq version without any notification): `var datas = $._data(HTML_ELEMENT, "events").click;
for (var i = datas.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(!datas[i].namespace) datas.splice(i,1);
}` or use instead: `if(!datas[i].namespace) $(HTML_ELEMENT).off('click', datas[i].handler);` inside loop

Comment: Works! Much appreciated :)